# Leaflet circle markers not adhering to my color palette? (R)

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to create a leaflet map with a custom palette that goes off of a range I have created. (Working in R btw)
Ideally something like this:[image]

However, the map I'm getting is: [image]

I'm not getting an error messages, but I just can't seem to get my circle markers to change color.

```
#import tax data
tax <- read_csv("state_cig_tax.csv")

#2016
tax16 <- tax  %>% 
  filter(year == "2016") 
#creating a range 
tax16$tax_range = cut(tax16$cig_tax,
                  breaks = c(0,.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,4.5),
                  labels = c("$0-0.50", "$0.51-1", "$1.01-1.50", "$1.51-2", "$2.01-2.50","$2.51-3", "$3+"))

#creating palette 
tax_pal <- colorFactor(c("purple","blue","green","yellow", "orange" ,"red", "black"), domain = tax16$tax_range)

#creating map
leaflet(data=tax16) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~ long,
                   lat = ~ lat, 
                   color = ~tax_pal(cig_tax),
                   label = ~as.character(state))%>% 
  addLegend("bottomright", pal = tax_pal, values = ~tax_range,
    title = "Cigarette Taxes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `color = ~tax_pal(tax_range)` instead of `color = ~tax_pal(cig_tax)`. You have set up a factor palette with values given by the levels of factor `tax_range`. However you want to map `cig_tax` on color, which has no values in common with the factor color palette. Hence, these are treated as NA and get a grey color. For the data I used to check it out I got a warning:

> Some values were outside the color scale and will be treated as NA.

Another option would be to use `colorBin` instead of `colorFactor`.